# Check values in a dictionary/list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to finish coding a game for my course programming. Basically, there's a checkerboard with different units placed on it. Let's say my dictionary looks like this:

```py
board = {'map': [{'x': 39, 'y': 41}],
         'hubs': [{'x': 21,
                   'y': 3,
                   'structure_points': 1000,
                   'capacity': 1500,
                   'regen_rate': 25},
                  {'x': 21,
                   'y': 38,
                   'structure_points': 1000,
                   'capacity': 1500,
                   'regen_rate': 25}],
         'peaks': [{'x': 10, 'y': 10, 'intensity': 200},
                   {'x': 11, 'y': 10, 'intensity': 300},
                   {'x': 12, 'y': 10, 'intensity': 400},
                   {'x': 10, 'y': 11, 'intensity': 200},
                   {'x': 10, 'y': 12, 'intensity': 500}]}
```

I want to 'check' if there is already an unit on one spot. For example, if I enter 21 and 38 as coordinates, how can my function tell me there's a hub there? I don't know if my question makes sense but I have no idea how to make it work. Any help would be very much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```py
def hub_exists(board, x, y):
    for hub in board.get('hubs', []):
        if hub.get('x') == x and hub.get('y') == y:
            return True
    return False
```

You iterate through all the hubs in the board dictionary, and return `True` if you find the correct one, otherwise after exhausting all the options, you return a `False`

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate over your list `board['hubs']` and check if any `dict` has your coordinates:

```
def check(x, y, board):
     return any(c['x'] == x and c['y'] == y  for c in board['hubs'])

check(21, 38, board)
```

output:

```
True
```